# Alternate port numbers for Supermicro IPMI View software

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, keyboard-video-mouse

I'm using the IPMI View software to manage a SuperMicro server but would like to use alternate port #s within the program itself. 
In other words - If I use the web browser, it defaults to port 80 - While I can, say change that port to 12345 (or whatever) and type the IP address into the browser (like http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12345 ) that works just fine. However, in IPMIView, it will assume port 80 and load the browser with the IP (which, naturally, won't work, so I have to manually type in the alternate port #).
I can deal with that.
The clincher is if I use a port other than 623 for management - (say 55623 for example), the IPMIView will not find it.
Same goes for the iKVM port #.
Is there some place to specify this (to tell IPMIView to use the alternate port numbers), like a settings file?

I'm running this from a Windows client.

Answer (score 1):

The IPMI specification does not define a way to change port 623 so the method to do this is dependent on the hardware vendor. SuperMicro uses multiple suppliers for it's IPMI implementations so you may find a way todo this on SuperMicro model and not on another.

Comment: I'll post this on a SuperMicro forum - they let you change the ports on the server end - surprised they don't have a way to do this with their client. There will be a VPN, ultimately, so perhaps my question is moot.